# Javascript click event is doubling every click

Tags: javascript

Would be really grateful for some advice with this javascript issue I am having with a click event that seems to be doubling every time my slider is closed then reopened.

When you open the slider for the first time and click through the slides you can see in the console the clicks incrementing by 1 every time the 'btn--next' is clicked which is of course correct. When i then close the slider down and re-open it again when the 'btn--next' is clicked the clicks in the console are now incrementing by 2 every click. Close the slider again and re-open and then the 'btn--next' clicks in the console increment by 3 and so on every time the slider is re-loaded.
https://jsfiddle.net/95afhtx8/2/

```
 var loadSlider = document.querySelector('.load__slider');


loadSlider.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var slider = document.querySelector('.animal__slider');
  var sliderSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.animal__slider__slide');
  var nextSlide = document.querySelector('.btn--next');
  var previousSlide = document.querySelector('.btn--previous');
  var closeSlider = document.querySelector('.animal__slider__close');
  var currentSlide = 0;

  slider.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    slider.classList.add('active--show');
    startSlide();
  }, 100);

  //Reset Slider
  function resetSlides() {
    for (var s = 0; s < sliderSlide.length; s++) {
      sliderSlide[s].classList.remove('active--show');
      sliderSlide[s].classList.remove('active');
    }
  }

  //Start Slider
  function startSlide() {
    resetSlides();
    sliderSlide[0].classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      sliderSlide[0].classList.add('active--show');
    }, 100);
  }

  //Previous slide
  function slidePrevious() {
    resetSlides();
    sliderSlide[currentSlide - 1].classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      sliderSlide[currentSlide].classList.add('active--show');
    }, 100);
    currentSlide--;
  }

  previousSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentSlide === 0) {
      currentSlide = sliderSlide.length;
    }
    console.log('click');
    slidePrevious();
  });

  //Next slide
  function slideNext() {
    resetSlides();
    sliderSlide[currentSlide + 1].classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      sliderSlide[currentSlide].classList.add('active--show');
    }, 100);
    currentSlide++;
  }

  nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentSlide === sliderSlide.length - 1) {
      currentSlide = -1;
    }
    console.log('click');
    slideNext();
  });

  closeSlider.addEventListener('click', function() {
    slider.classList.remove('active--show');
    slider.classList.remove('active');
    resetSlides();
  });
});
```

Comment: You're accumulating event listeners every time you open the slider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because every time you click on your slider toggle:

```
loadSlider[s].addEventListener('click', function () {
```

You're re-running code like this, which will add another click handler to the element:

```
 nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
```

You can add multiple event listeners to any object in the DOM. So you just keep adding more every time the slider opens.

You have three general options here.

**Option 1: only set click handlers once**

Don't re-add event handlers inside your `loadSlider[s].addEventListener('click', function () {` function. Do it outside so you aren't re-adding handlers.

**Option 2: remove click handlers on close**

You can remove the event listeners on close. To do this, you should store a reference to the function you make, so you can explicitly remove it later. You should do this for any handlers you add.

```
const nextClick = function () {
    ...
};
nextSlide.addEventListener('click', nextClick);

function resetSlides() {
    nextSlide.removeEventListener('click', nextClick);
    ...
}
```

This way, when the slider is hidden, the click functionality will be turned off, and re-opening it will add new click handlers and the old ones won't fire because you removed them.

**Option 3: Re-create the elements**

If you remove an element from the DOM and make a completely new one, the new one won't have stale click handlers on it. This means you'll need to dynamically build your markup with Javascript (using `document.createElement`), not store it in the HTML page body.

Comment: thanks so much for this, i have just updated the JS code in the post to represent the code in the fiddle example

Comment: thanks again for this, I think option 2 is looking like the best way to go. Out of curiosity though would you be able to give me an example of how option 1 would work? I am still learning javascript slowly so I’m not to sure how to do it

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you call `nextSlide.addEventListener(...)` each time you open the slider, but you never remove that listener. you have to call the function `nextSlide.removeEventListener(...)` when you close the slider. You also can make sure to call `addEventListener` only when you open the slider the first time, or even before you open it, as the html element is never destroyed.

To be able to remove the listener, you have to make it accessible in your code when you close the slider. You can't use anonymous functions for this.

EDIT :
An other, simpler solution is to change

`nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function(){...});`

to:

`nextSlide['onclick'] = function() {...};`

Answer (score 1):

I update your code to work properly (you need to close the anonymous function of the first event listener before you start declaring the others, otherwise you are copying them over and over and therefore the doubling/quadrupling etc...). I would also suggest to move DOM selectors outside of the event listener, they can evaluate only once:

```js
var loadSlider = document.querySelector('.load__slider');

var slider = document.querySelector('.animal__slider');
var sliderSlide = document.querySelectorAll('.animal__slider__slide');
var nextSlide = document.querySelector('.btn--next');
var previousSlide = document.querySelector('.btn--previous');
var closeSlider = document.querySelector('.animal__slider__close');
var currentSlide = 0;

loadSlider.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slider.classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    slider.classList.add('active--show');
    startSlide();
  }, 100);
});

//Reset Slider
function resetSlides() {
  for (var s = 0; s < sliderSlide.length; s++) {
    sliderSlide[s].classList.remove('active--show');
    sliderSlide[s].classList.remove('active');
  }
}

//Start Slider
function startSlide() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[0].classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sliderSlide[0].classList.add('active--show');
  }, 100);
}

//Previous slide
function slidePrevious() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[currentSlide - 1].classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sliderSlide[currentSlide].classList.add('active--show');
  }, 100);
  currentSlide--;
}

previousSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (currentSlide === 0) {
    currentSlide = sliderSlide.length;
  }
  console.log('click');
  slidePrevious();
});

//Next slide
function slideNext() {
  resetSlides();
  sliderSlide[currentSlide + 1].classList.add('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    sliderSlide[currentSlide].classList.add('active--show');
  }, 100);
  currentSlide++;
}

nextSlide.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (currentSlide === sliderSlide.length - 1) {
    currentSlide = -1;
  }
  console.log('click');
  slideNext();
});

closeSlider.addEventListener('click', function() {
  slider.classList.remove('active--show');
  slider.classList.remove('active');
  resetSlides();
});
```

```css
.animals {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

.load__slider {
  text-align: center;
}

.animal__slider {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.animal__slider.active {
  display: block;
}

.animal__slider.active .animal__slider__close {
  display: block;
}

.animal__slider.active+.animal__slider__open {
  opacity: 0;
}

.animal__slider__slide {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.animal__slider__slide1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.animal__slider__slide2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.animal__slider__slide3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.animal__slider__slide4 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.animal__slider__slide.active {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn--previous {
  right: 60px;
}

.btn--next {
  right: 30px;
}

.animal__slider__close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animal__slider__open {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="animals">

  <div class="animal__slider">
    Slider
    <div class="animal__slider__slide animal__slider__slide1">
      slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="animal__slider__slide animal__slider__slide2">
      slide 2
    </div>
    <div class="animal__slider__slide animal__slider__slide3">
      slide 3
    </div>
    <div class="animal__slider__slide animal__slider__slide4">
      slide 4
    </div>
    <span class="btn btn--previous">previous</span>
    <span class="btn btn--next">next</span>
    <span class="animal__slider__close">close slider</span>
  </div>
  <span class="animal__slider__open load__slider">open slider</span>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks so much for this, i have been pulling my hair out nearly 2 days trying to work out what is going on!